# GAS: "You have run the service premium gmail too many times a day" issu

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, quota

MY GAS that automatically saves email attachments to a certain Google Drive folder is returning below error.

## Error

> You have run the service premium gmail too many times a day.
> at getCandidateMailMessages(download_pdf_attachments:139)
> at process(download_pdf_attachments:20)
> at processPdfAttachmentsDownload(download_pdf_attachments:323)

I'm using GSuite Business edition but it seems like it's hitting the daily quota listed below. [app script service quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

The problem is that I don't know which feature's quota I'm maxing out, and if there is such plan that I can upgrade to, to increase the quota capacity.

Comment: As far as i know this is an app script limitation and not a gmail limitation.   Its there to protect app script from spam.  Your basically making to many requests.  You need to tune your code so that it makes fewer requests.

Comment: G Suite Business edition alreadyt gives you the maximum possible quota, but if you provide your code it would be easiert to tell which quota exactly you are hitting and try to optimize your code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those who have already commented. You can't really change the limits. You have basically a few options:

1. Reduce the number of times per day your script runs.
2. Reduce the number of times you are calling the API in a given time period by optimizing your code, (which we can't help you with unless we know what your code looks like).
3. Figure out a different way to do what you are trying to do.